# How to get the total quantity of results using count(*)?

Tags: oracle11g

i need to get the total quantity of results for each person but i get ...

[resultado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyixm.png)

MY QUERY..

```
select t.fecha_hora_timbre,e.nombre,e.apellido,d.descripcion as departamento_trabaja, t.fecha,count(*)
from fulltime.timbre t, fulltime.empleado e, fulltime.departamento d
where d.depa_id=e.depa_id and t.codigo_empleado=e.codigo_empleado and
            trunc(t.fecha) between trunc(to_date('15/02/2017','dd/mm/yyyy')) and trunc(to_date('14/03/2017','dd/mm/yyyy'))

group by t.fecha_hora_timbre,e.nombre,e.apellido,d.descripcion, t.fecha
```

Expected data...

```
NOMBRE          | APELLIDO       | DEPARTAMENTO_TRABAJA  | VECES_MARCADAS(count)
MARIA TARCILA     IGLESIAS BECERRA         ALCALDIA               4
KATHERINE TATIANA SEGOVIA FERNANDEZ        ALCALDIA               10
FREDDY AGUSTIN    VALDIVIESO VALLEJO       ALCALDIA               3
```

UPDATE..

```
select e.nombre,e.apellido,d.descripcion as departamento_trabaja,COUNT(*)
from fulltime.timbre t, fulltime.empleado e, fulltime.departamento d
where d.depa_id=e.depa_id and t.codigo_empleado=e.codigo_empleado and
            trunc(t.fecha) between trunc(to_date('15/02/2017','dd/mm/yyyy')) and trunc(to_date('14/03/2017','dd/mm/yyyy'))

group by t.fecha_hora_timbre,e.nombre,e.apellido,d.descripcion, t.fecha
```

Comment: You're selecting(and grouping by) a lot of columns; you'll see the count for each unique combination of all of those. Do you want to see fewer columns - without the `fecha_hora_timbre` and `fecha` probably - with the count for the remaining columns; or do you want to keep all of those columns and have the total count for each person as well; so the all three rows for 'Maria Tarcila' are shown but each has a count of '3' appended?

Comment: If you [show your output as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and include your expected results we'd have a better idea what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: HI!!! @Alex Poole thanks!! Well, I need to keep the total quantity for each person for example: [example](http://i.imgur.com/dND6MuI.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to show text, not images. You are currently selecting and grouping by more columns that that - why? Remove the columns you don't want to group by (from both parts of the query)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only select and group by the non-aggregate columns you actually want to count against. At the moment you're including the `fecha_hora_timbre` and `fecha`columns in each row, so you're counting the unique combinations of those columns as well as the name/department information you actually want to count.

```
select e.nombre, e.apellido, d.descripcion as departamento_trabaja,
  count(*) a veces_marcadas
from fulltime.timbre t
join fulltime.empleado e on t.codigo_empleado=e.codigo_empleado
join fulltime.departamento d on d.depa_id=e.depa_id
where t.fecha >= to_date('15/02/2017','dd/mm/yyyy')
and t.fecha < to_date('15/03/2017','dd/mm/yyyy')
group by e.nombre, e.apellido, d.descripcion
```

I've removed the extra columns. Notice that they have gone from both the select list and the group-by clause. If you have a non-aggregate column in the select list that isn't in the group-by you'll get an ORA-00937 error; but if you have a column in the group-by that isn't in the select list then it will still group by that even though you can't see it and you just won't get the results you expect.

I've also changed from old-style join syntax to modern syntax. And I've changed the date comparison; firstly because doing `trunc()` as part of `trunc(to_date('15/02/2017','dd/mm/yyyy'))` is pointless - you already know the time part is midnight, so the trunc doesn't achieve anything. But mostly so that if there is an index on `fecha` that index can be used. If you do `trunc(f.techa)` then the value of every column value has to be truncated, which stops the index being used (unless you have a function-based index). As `between` in inclusive, using `>=` and `<` with one day later on the higher limit should have the same effect overall.